# Payment gateways for Europe (Netherlands)?

Tags: ecommerce, payments, paypal, payment-gateway

I've just realized all Paypal payment gateways are not available in Europe.

Only Website payment standard is working, but it is not a gateway, I cannot include the payment process into my website.

I was now wondering what safe payment gateways to use for my e-commerce website in Netherlands.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Worldpay](http://www.rbsworldpay.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[iDEAL](http://www.google.nl/search?q=ideal+paypal) is pretty much the standard in the Netherlands, and it's far more popular than Paypal.

Comment: The point is that iDeal doesn't allow me to accept credit cards payments.

Comment: Payment with credit card is not so common in the Netherlands (although it is very widely supported).  In shops we pay with debit cards using our PIN. iDEAL extends this to the web.  I got a credit card for a trip to the US and canceled it since - I never need one.  A Dutch website with only credit card payment will raise some eyebrows.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept major credit cards and also net banks from Denmark you can try Gogopay Payment Gateway. They accept payment in 35 currencies. Check their website www.gogopay.com.

Answer (score 0):

try Google checkout, yahoo shop card